# What does "if (double)" do in C++

Tags: java, c++, syntax, translation

I can't seem to get this figured out, or I already made it work but somewhere in my code is another bug...

My question is, can someone translate this C++ code

```
if (!fmod(x[i][j], 1) && x[i][j]) {
```

to the Java equivelent.
The variable x has doubles in it's list.

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: FYI, in the future it would be better do give a more descriptive name to your question. For example, you could have said _What does "if (double)" do in C++?_ since—based on your comment on jh314's answer—that's what was actually confusing you.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better, I will try to edit the question so Google does index it there anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (x[i][j] % 1 == 0 && x[i][j] != 0 ) {
```

Java doesn't do automatic coercions to the Boolean type, so you have to make Boolean values with `!=` and `==`, etc. This just checks to that the double at `x[i][j]` is a non-zero whole number. (In C++, anything non-zero is `true` and zero is `false`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `%` operator instead of `fmod`:

```
if ((x[i][j] % 1.0 == 0) && (x[i][j] != 0)) {
```

Comment: This is not correct since "if (double)" does not do anything in Java. I have no idea what it does in C++...